# Hello SO, i just changed a React with MartyJS flux from SSR to Client side rendering, having issues with react-router

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router, martyjs

So as the title describes im doing an app available on github  at denlillemand/react. It has a express backend that just serves a simple html template that imports my bundle.js. And the app initially renders just fine, but none of the routes seem to work.

Below is the components that are involved:

./Application.js

```
   import React from "react"; 
   import Marty from "marty"; 
   import actions from "./actions";
   import stores from "./stores";
   import queries from "./queries";
   import sources from "./sources";
   import Router from "./Router";
   import RealApp from "./components/App";

class Application extends Marty.Application {
  constructor(options) {
  super(options);
  this.register(actions);
  this.register(stores); 
  this.register(queries);
  this.register(sources);
  this.router = Router;
  }
}

var app = new Application();
var { ApplicationContainer }  = require('marty');

app.router.run(function(Handler,state){
      React.render((
              <ApplicationContainer app={app}>
                      <Handler{...state} />           
              </ApplicationContainer>         
      ), document.getElementById("app"));
});
```

./components/App.js

```
 import React from "react"; 
 import Router from "react-router";
 import Header from "./core/Header";
 import Footer from "./core/Footer";

 var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

 export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {     
    super(props);          
    this.state = {         
    }
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>                
       <Header />           
       <RouteHandler />
       <Footer />           
      </div>               
     );
   }
}
```

./Routes.js

```
 import React from "react";
 import {Route} from "react-router";
 import {DefaultRoute} from "react-router";
 import App from "./components/App";
 import About from "./components/About";
 import ChapterOne from "./components/chapterone/ChapterOne";
 import ChapterTwo from "./components/chaptertwo/ChapterTwo";
 import ChapterThree from "./components/chapterthree/ChapterThree";
 import ChapterFour from "./components/chapterfour/ChapterFour";

  export default (
          <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
                <Route path="/about" handler={About}/>
                <Route path="/chapters/chapterone" handler={ChapterOne} />
                 <Route path="/chapters/chaptertwo" handler={ChapterTwo} />
                 <Route path="/chapters/chapterthree" handler={ChapterThree} />
                 <Route path="/chapters/chapterfour" handler={ChapterFour} />
                 <DefaultRoute name="default" handler={About}/>
         </Route>
  );
```

./Router.js

```
  import Router from "react-router";
  import routes from "./Routes";

  let location = () => {
       if(typeof window !== undefined){
         return Router.historyLocation;
       }
   } 

    export default Router.create({
         routes:routes,
         location:location()
     });
```

The default route seems to be the only one that works, since im hitting the About component. This app worked when it was SSR not long ago, and im kind of wondering if ive setup react-router correctly, but looking at the DOCS it seem like i have.

Answer (score 0):

i guess i have to answer my own question,

The creator of MartyJS recently killed off his own project,
if you follow his twitter he announced it ..
so i guess im moving to redux since it has like 3500+ github starts i suppose it will be easier to find support for redux issues that arise .

Thanks .